# how to store specific cells into an array? vba-excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have this:
        column A
        row1: str1;str2;str3
        row2: str4;str5;str6
        row3: str7;str8;str9
        ....................
        rown: strn;strn;strn

The code below finds ";" character into the column A:

```
     Range("A:A").Find(What:=";", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
     xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

I want to put all rows (from column A, containing semicolon character) into an array. I tried to use SET, like this:

```
       dim r as Variant
       Set r = Range("A:A").Find(What:=rngsearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=_  
       xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,MatchCase:=False _
       , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

...but doesn't work. It's run-time error '13', type mismatch

I need this array (containing all the cells with semicolon) because I want to extract the strings (from str1 to strn) and separate them in different rows.

Can anyone help me? Maybe someone has another idea how I can do this?

Comment: Why don't you use an autofilter with "*;*" as the criteria, then loop through the visible cells?

Comment: Do you want to add arr(0) = str1, arr(1) = str2, arr(3) = str3, arr(n) = strn like this?

Comment: Yes,  @Jagadish Dabbiru

Comment: @Rory, I have to use VBA code..

Comment: I meant using VBA code - I wasn't expecting you to do it by hand. :)

Comment: sorry @Rory, I didn't understand what you meant. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this, I would personally prefer to avoid referring to an entire column, but this should hopefully do what you are expecting:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim strTmp As String
Dim arrFinal As Variant

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")

' Loop through all cells in column A
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    ' Is there a semicolon character in the cell?
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, ";") > 0 Then
        ' Add the cell value to strTmp and add a _
            semicolon at the end to separate this _
            row from the next row
        strTmp = strTmp & cel.Value & ";"
    End If
Next cel

' Split strTmp into an array
arrFinal = Split(strTmp, ";")

End Sub
```

The end result Is an array called arrFinal of all strings between the semicolon characters

Comment: thank you a lot! That is what I need. 

But if I need the string upto or after the semicolon (I mean put in a new row the string), I have to manipulate the Split line code, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to something like this:

```
Sub GetSemicolonData()
    Dim rngCell               As Excel.Range
    Dim asValues()            As String
    Dim lngCount              As Long
    Dim x                     As Long


    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*;*"
        lngCount = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
        If lngCount > 1 Then
            x = 1
            ' exclude header row
            ReDim asValues(1 To lngCount - 1)
            For Each rngCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If rngCell.Row > 1 Then
                    ' load value into array
                    asValues(x) = rngCell.Value
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next rngCell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You could also use a variation of Dave's approach that loads all the data into an array and processes that - it should be faster than cell by cell reads.

Comment: your idea is great too! But yes, Dave's code processes faster. Thank you anyway!